# Using application variables in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, database

In my site I have a static table that stores information. I wonder if I should store all this information in an Application so there would be less database calls. Would it be more efficient? Is there other solutions or calling the database constantly for static information is no so bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better question is whether it would make a significant difference in performance.

What you're doing is called "premature optimization". You are optimizing for performance before you know where your performance problems are located. In fact, you are doing so even before your application is complete.

- First get your application to work.
- Then get your application to work fast enough.

There's no sense in having your application fail in an efficient manner.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still need an answer for my question.

Comment: That was the answer: don't worry about it. You're likely solving the wrong problem.

Comment: OK, you may be right. I will come back with this question later, when my site is nearly finished.